# JQuery UI buttonset not working on radio buttons when I associate runat="server" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am creating a demo application, where I want to use radio buttons as buttons. For that I am using JQuery UI buttonset widget. It was working fine before but the actual problem began when I introduced the attribute runat="server", in order to retain the state during a post back. But after applying the attribute, buttonset widget stopped working on radio buttons.

So, I just want a solution where I can retain the state of the radio button controls and at the same time apply buttonset widget on them.

```
    <div id="genderOptions">
        <input type="radio" id="genderMale" value="Male" name="gender" />
        <label for="genderMale" >Male </label>
        <input type="radio" id="genderFemale" value="Female" name="gender"/>
        <label for="genderFemale" >Female </label>
    </div>
```

[Output without runat="server" attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLHEv.jpg)

```
    <div id="genderOptions">
        <input type="radio" id="genderMale" value="Male" name="gender" runat="server" />
        <label for="genderMale" >Male </label>
        <input type="radio" id="genderFemale" value="Female" name="gender" runat="server" />
         <label for="genderFemale" >Female </label>
    </div>
```

[This is the final output after specifying the attribute runat="server"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGwhD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The `runat="server"` attribute used to dynamically change `id` and `name` attributes. Verify your rendered markup. Probably you will see something like
`<input type="radio" id="ctl00_genderMale" value="Male" name="ctl00$gender" />`
I assume you specify the input fields using ids in your JS which initializes the buttonset widget. Try to use tag or class selectors instead:

```
$("#genderOptions").buttonset({
    items: "input[type=radio]"
});
```

Comment: Well, I used the same approach that you have mentioned but it's not giving me the output that I need.

Comment: Could you please provide the JS code you use for widget initialization? As a dirty workaround you can leave the radiobuttons without `runat="server"` attributes, create a pair of hidden inputs with `runat="server"` attrributes and copy the values there from radios using JS when submitting the form. Just in case we cannot find the root of the issue.

Comment: Instead of using hidden fields, I converted HTML controls into ASP.net controls. That solved the purpose for me.